# jQuery: trigger dropdown when div or its childnodes are clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a menubar with divs as items. When the items are clicked, a dropdown opens. If the user clicks somewhere else, on a link in the dropdown or on another menubar-item the dropdown disappears. So far so good. But when a child of the menubar-div is clicked, nothing happens.

This is the show and hide logic:

```
var state = $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden');
if (state === 'true') {
  $('body').not(this).find('.dropdown-content').hide();
  $('body').not(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
  if ($('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().hasClass('secondarycolor')) {
    $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().addClass('hoversecondary');
    $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().removeClass('secondarycolor');
  }
  console.log('A' + $(event.target).attr('class'));
  console.log('B' + $(this).attr('class'));
  console.log('C' + $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('class'));
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').show();
  if ($(this).hasClass('hoversecondary')) {
    $(this).addClass('secondarycolor');
    $(this).removeClass('hoversecondary');
  }
} else {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').hide();
  if ($(this).hasClass('secondarycolor')) {
    $(this).addClass('hoversecondary');
    $(this).removeClass('secondarycolor');
  }
  $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
}
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6db2pt98/) and a snippet:

```js
$('.dropdown-button').click(function() {
  if (!($(event.target).hasClass('dropdown-content') || $(event.target).parents('.dropdown-content').length > 0)) {
    var state = $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden');
    if (state === 'true') {
      $('body').not(this).find('.dropdown-content').hide();
      $('body').not(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
      if ($('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().hasClass('secondarycolor')) {
        $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().addClass('hoversecondary');
        $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().removeClass('secondarycolor');
      }
      console.log('A' + $(event.target).attr('class'));
      console.log('B' + $(this).attr('class'));
      console.log('C' + $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('class'));
      $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
      $(this).find('.dropdown-content').show();
      if ($(this).hasClass('hoversecondary')) {
        $(this).addClass('secondarycolor');
        $(this).removeClass('hoversecondary');
      }
    } else {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-content').hide();
      if ($(this).hasClass('secondarycolor')) {
        $(this).addClass('hoversecondary');
        $(this).removeClass('secondarycolor');
      }
      $(this).find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    }
  }
});
$('body').click(function() {
  if (($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-content').length === 0 && $(event.target).children('.dropdown-content').length === 0 && !$(event.target).hasClass('dropdown-content')) || ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-content').length > 0 && $(event.target).parent().prop("tagName") === 'A')) {
    $('body').find('.dropdown-content').hide();
    $('body').find('.dropdown-content').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
    if ($('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().hasClass('secondarycolor')) {
      $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().addClass('hoversecondary');
      $('body').find('.dropdown-content').parent().removeClass('secondarycolor');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.topmenu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #17accc;
}

.topmenuitem {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 42px;
}

.userimage {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoversecondary:hover {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.secondarycolor {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topmenu">
  <div class="topmenuitem dropdown-button hoversecondary"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw" aria-hidden="true">Q</i>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="Q" aria-hidden="true">
      <a href="#"><span>Q1</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Q2</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topmenuitem dropdown-button hoversecondary"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw" aria-hidden="true">S</i> <img class="userimage" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-400-400-1.jpg" />
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="S" aria-hidden="true">
      <a href="#"><span>S1</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>S2</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

How can i trigger the dropdown when a child of the menu-item-div is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself. The dropdown was always showing up correctly, but the onclick on the body was triggered, when an other element then dropdown-content was pressed. I updated the condition like this:

```
if (($(evt.target).parents('.dropdown-content').length === 0 && $(evt.target).children('.dropdown-content').length === 0 && !$(evt.target).hasClass('dropdown-content') && $(evt.target).parent().children('.dropdown-content').length === 0) || ($(evt.target).parents('.dropdown-content').length > 0 && $(evt.target).parent().prop("tagName") === 'A')) {
```

Addidionally i had to add a event-parameter to the fuction so it works on firefox.

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8kkxdp2/)